# How to Update multiple columns in a batch using PySQLPool?

Tags: python, mysql

```
import PySQLPool
connection = PySQLPool.getNewConnection(username='root', password='123456', host='localhost', db='mydb')
query = PySQLPool.getNewQuery(connection)
```

How to use this query to execute updations in batch?

```
update info set info="ichi" where msisdn1=XXX and msisdn2=yyyy
update info set info="ni" where msisdn1=XXX and msisdn2=PPP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit  of Struggle and looking into PySQLPool. I have found this.

sample = """UPDATE userscore SET info="%s" WHERE msisdn1=%s and msisdn2=%s"""
data = [('ichi',911234123412,16502522222),('ni',911234123412,16502326969),('san',911234123412,919999683)]

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html